# Plotting a 3d figure in Matlab given a table

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure, probability

The table I have is like this:
[An image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQmbZ.png)

| X↓ Y-> | Y = 0 | Y = 1 | Y = 2 | Y = 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X = 3 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 4/54 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 3/54 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 2/54 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 1/54 |
| X = 5 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 6/54 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 5/54 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 4/54 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 3/54 |
| X = 7 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 8/54 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 7/54 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 6/54 | P<sub>XY</sub> = 5/54 |

P<sub>XY</sub> is given by (x - y + 1)/54

How should I go about graphing this on MATLAB? I wish to draw a 3d histogram, something like this:

[image: plot].

Most of my attempts have ended in errors usually because the X and Y vectors are not the same length.

If there's ways to do this Python as well, then please let me know, that works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab, you can use `histogram2` specifying the edges of the bins in the x and y direction and the bin count.

```
% Your data
x = [3; 5; 7];
y = [0, 1, 2, 3];
p = (x - y + 1)/54;
% since x is a column vector and y a row vector, as of Matlab R2016b this results in a length(x)*length(y) matrix, equivalent to:
% p = zeros(length(x), length(y));
% for ix = 1:length(x)
%    for iy = 1:length(y)
%        p(ix, iy) = (x(ix) - y(iy) + 1)/54;
%    end
% end

% Plot the histogram
histogram2('XBinEdges', [x; 9], ...
           'YBinEdges', [y, 4], ...
           'BinCounts', p);
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('P_{xy}')
```

Since you need 3 bins for x (4 bins for y), you need to provide 4 edges (5 edges for y), hence the additional points in the `histogram2` call.

EDIT: on second thought, you probably want the bins centered on the x and y points that you provide, so perhaps you might want to use `xEdges = [x - 1; x(end) + 1]` and `yEdges = [y - 0.5, y(end) + 0.5]` as bin edges instead.

Comment: It's slightly non-obvious here that you're relying on implicit expansion to make a matrix `p` from operating on a row and column vector together, and that this will only work since MATLAB R2016b.

Comment: @Wolfie true enough, I added a small commented line regarding this, thanks. Also didn't know this was only introduced in 2016!

Comment: Here is the release post from when the functionality was added for info, there are examples using `bsxfun` which was the precursor: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/